# how to fill div content till the right div?

Tags: css, html, fill

Hello my question is how to fill the div with the min-width (Central one) till the right div and not destroy him

**CSS**

```
    .test
    {
        height : 800px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<body style="background-color:#e5e5e5;margin: 0">
    <div>
        <div style="
        height              : 37px;
    width               : 100%;
        background-color    : #3b5998;
    -webkit-box-shadow  : 0 2px 2px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .52);
    border-bottom       : 1px solid black;
    ">
        <div style="padding-top: 6px;margin-left: 76px;">
            <img src="images/logo-text.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- -->
    <div>
        <div class="test" style="float : left;width: 130px;background-color : #e5e5e5"></div>
        <div class="test" style="min-width: 800px;background-color: white;"></div>
        <div class="test" style="float : right;width: 130px;background-color : red"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="background-color : #e5e5e5;width : 100%;height: 100px">
</div>
</body>
```

FULL CODE
[1] http://pastebin.com/phrDAbPw

*Thanks*

Comment: You don't need to float everything. Use `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` to make them sit next to each other than set the width.

Comment: hello dear maybe you can post any example?

Answer (score 1):

Floating the outside divs is not the way to do it. You can use `display: inline` or `display: inline-block` to make div elements stay inline. Without knowing your exact specification, here is a simple example:

**Inline CSS**

```
<div style="display: block;">
    <div class="test" style="display: inline-block;width: 130px;background-color: #e5e5e5">hi</div>
    <div class="test" style="display: inline-block;width: 800px;background-color: white;">hey</div>
    <div class="test" style="display: inline-block;width: 130px;background-color: red">ho</div>
</div>
```

Also note, this will not scale at all--meaning mobile devices and users with lower resolutions will have scroll bars. Consider using percentage based widths to accomodate. Otherwise, this is a start.

Comment: first thanks , im not talking about mobile only computer screens i need the left side go maximum left and the right side go maximum right and center div stay in center any solution for this thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to destroy it just use max-width. But why do you not work with %-widths? 
For Example:

```
<div id="left">

</div>
<div id="main">

</div>
<div id="right">

</div>
```

Css:

```
#left {
min-width: 200px;
width: 20%;
}

#main {
min-width: 700px;
width: 60%;
}

#right {
min-width: 150px;
width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: idk maybe this bcoz this is the only way i know ? anyway i trying to make this kinda of template for all web screens http://oi50.tinypic.com/21eq0jl.jpg